# Extract eclipse project .classpath dependencies into ant script

Tags: eclipse, ant, javac

I have a list of Eclipse projects that I would like to compile based on the existing project configuration.

As far as I can tell, if an ant script could read the .classpath files, it would pretty much be able to infer the project dependencies and perform a "javac" compilation in the right order. This would save time in describing the same dependencies again in the ant script or a Makefile.

The dependencies I am interested in are JAR Dependencies, JRE dependencies, and inter-project dependencies. These are -- as far as I can tell -- part of the .classpath XML file.

Any ideas on how Eclipse project dependencies could used in an ant script?

Comment: Do you want to export your eclipse project into ant build file?

Comment: Well -- that is also a possibility. Although having an ant file that can read directly from existing Eclipse projects would be ideal. That way I do not have to reimport with every change to the Eclipse projects.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Right click on your Project -> Export 
"General/Ant Buildfiles".
Choose the projects and there you go.

Otherwise...
I have some experience with ant4eclipse and it is a hassle to get it stable.

Go check Buckminster or Maven Tycho for a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers -- I believe ant4eclipse should do the trick. I am looking for a way to keep the main dev on eclipse and run occasional ant scripts based on that every now and then.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using Ivy along with Ant, Eclipse and Maven.

I just love the way Ivy works.

Currently, we have a workspace with many projects using Liferay (with Tomcat) for the front-end and Glassfish for the back-end.

We were looking for a way to manage our dependencies a lot better than how we were doing it.

So I took Ivy, replaced all of the classpaths and deployment dependencies in eclipse and was able to build my application using 1 ivy file per project using either Eclipse or Ant.
Ivy integrates like a charm in ant and builds are done either from the workspace or by command line.

I strongly suggest you look at this avenue. Additionnaly, by adding Artifactory, we have a local repository in which the ivy files look for dependencies. This helps us maintain and rule which jars are to be used by developpers. Once everything is setup, we will build our application nightly using Jenkins and these builds will be using our Artifactory repository to resolve dependencies since our build servers do not have access to the internet.

Hope this helped

Comment: I agree whole heartedly with Pat B about Ivy. It didnt make sense to use Eclipse and Ant build use different methods of figuring out and providing project jar deps. Now it's in one very simple file: ivy.xml I highly recommend finding and reading ApacheIvyBeginnersGuide.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the Ant script only from eclipse using the "External Tools Configurations", you can add the variable ${project_classpath} to the Classpath.

Depending on if you are in a plugin project and dependencies you might need to add the 
${eclipse_home}.

In case you get an error launching `Variable references empty selection: ${project_classpath}`, make sure the ant xml file or at least the project is selected. This is important.

Comment: I get the error `Variable references empty selection: ${project_classpath}` a lot.  I decided to remove `${project_classpath}` and manually add in the necessary jars.  This seems to be working well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [ant4eclipse](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/) project provides support for executing Ant builds based on Eclipse metadata files.

However, in my opinion that is doing things back to front. You shouldn't have your build (Ant) depending on your IDE (Eclipse) environment. But it is useful if you can derive your Eclipse environment from your Ant build.

This is an approach used successfully in a team I worked in. We had a helper Ant target which applied XLST to project `build.xml` files to transform these into Eclipse `.classpath` files. Thus the Ant `build.xml` files were the single configuration point for our projects.